# how to draw two tree in one graph with graphviz, that one is top to bottom while the other is bottom to top

Tags: graphviz

I have a digraph

```
digraph BST {
subgraph{
s00  [ label = "s00" ]; 
s00 -> { s10 s11 s12}; 
s10  [ label = "s10" ]; 
s10 -> { s22 s23 }; 
s11  [ label = "s11" ]; 
s11 -> { }; 
s12  [ label = "s12" ]; 
s12 -> { }; 
s22  [ label = "s22" ]; 
s22 -> { }; 
s23  [ label = "s23" ]; 
s23 -> { s30 s31 }; 
s30  [ label = "s30" ]; 
s30 -> { }; 
s31  [ label = "s31" ]; 
s31 -> { }; 
}

subgraph{
g00  [ label = "g00" ]; 
g00 -> { g10 g11 g111 }; 
g10  [ label = "g10" ]; 
g10 -> { }; 
g11  [ label = "g11" ]; 
g11 -> { }; 
g111  [ label = "g111" ]; 
g111 -> { g20 }; 
g20  [ label = "g20" ]; 
g20 -> { g30 g31 g32 }; 
g30  [ label = "g30" ]; 
g30 -> { }; 
g31  [ label = "g31" ]; 
g31 -> { }; 
g32  [ label = "g32" ]; 
g32 -> { }; 
}

}
```

how to make the tree start from g00 inverted(grow from bottom to top)， and node s00 has the same x coordinate value with g00(Vertically aligned), and add a edge from g31 to s30.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `dir` attribute of the edges in the g subgraph, like so:

```
digraph {
    subgraph{
        node [fillcolor = red, style = filled]
        s00 -> { s10 s11 s12}; 
        s10 -> { s22 s23 }; 
        s23 -> { s30 s31 }; 
    }
    subgraph{
        edge [dir = back]
        node [fillcolor = blue, style = filled]
        { g10 g11 g111 } -> g00;
        { g20 } -> g111; 
        { g30 g31 g32 } -> g20; 
    }
}
```

I simplified your code a bit and used colors to mark the different graphs.
It will look like this when using the dot layout:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cY6J.png)

Edit:
To "shift" one of the subgraphs up you can insert a couple of invisible nodes (however many levels you want to shift):

```
digraph {
    subgraph{
        node [fillcolor = red, style = filled]
        {
            node [style = invis]
            invis1 invis2 invis3
        }
        invis1 -> invis2 -> invis3 -> s00 [style = invis]
        s00 -> { s10 s11 s12}; 
        s10 -> { s22 s23 }; 
        s23 -> { s30 s31 }; 
    }
    subgraph{
        edge [dir = back]
        node [fillcolor = blue, style = filled]
        { g10 g11 g111 } -> g00;
        { g20 } -> g111; 
        { g30 g31 g32 } -> g20; 
    }
}
```

Looks like this: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTPW0.png)

Comment: Thanks!  And I also want the g00 and s00 be posed on one vertical line. can that be realized?

Comment: Yes it's possible however my solution is quite hacky. I'm sure there is a better way. I have updated my answer